# isotope & Infinite Scroll with manual triggering

Tags: jquery-isotope, infinite-scroll

I'm using Isotope plugin with Infinite Scroll plugin. With the default settings Infinite Scroll automatically triggers loading new elements which is fine, however, I would rather have a button "Load more images".

I'm only missing a small piece of code that will get new elements from Infinite scroll that I can pass to isotope INSERT function. Please see my comments below in code:

```
// initialize infinite scroll
$container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '#paging',    // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : '#paging a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : '.col',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    loading: {
        msgText: 'Loading...',
        finishedMsg: Loaded all!',
             }
    } // <-- NOTE that we do not use callback function here!
    );


$(window).unbind('.infscr'); 

$('#paging a').click(function(){

// NEED CODE HERE TO GET NEW ELEMENTS FROM INFINITE SCROLL AND PASS THOSE ELEMENTS TO $container.isotope('insert', $(newElements)); 

});
```

Comment: But - when you're not automatically appending new elements by a user's scrolling down and use a button to append new elements - don't you then just need to use http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/adding-items.html and, well, append? Infinite scroll without appending automatically is no infinite scroll anymore, isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

The infinite scroll plugin actually offers a ["manual-trigger"-behavior](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/blob/master/behaviors/manual-trigger.js) to do just what you're after.

Include `manual-trigger.js` after `jquery.infinitescroll.js`, tell infinite scroll to use the behavior by passing `behavior: 'twitter'` when calling the plugin, then just call Isotope as a callback as demonstrated in [Isotope's demo for Infinite Scroll](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/infinite-scroll.html):

```
$container.infinitescroll({
  navSelector  : '#paging',
  nextSelector : '#paging a',
  itemSelector : '.col',
  behavior: 'twitter',
  loading: {
      msgText: 'Loading...',
      finishedMsg: 'Loaded all!'
    }
  },
  // call Isotope as a callback
  function( newElements ) {
    $container.isotope( 'appended', $( newElements ) ); 
  }
);
```